# How to show a Tab if mouse pointer axis in a particular location using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag

```
<li><a href="#inline_content1" class="inline1"  ></a></li>
```

and dynamically insert to two `<p>` tags into the anchor tag

```
<p>Tab1</p>
```

and

```
<p> Tab2</p>
```

Now code shows following:

```
<li>
     <a href="#inline_content1" class="inline1"  >
         <p>Tab1</p> 
         <p> Tab2</p>
     </a>
</li>
```

If the user clicks on the anchor tag, there is shows a popup. That popup has two tabs, I want to show the Tab1 on the popup if somebody click on the  `<p>Tab1</p>` and vice versa.

```
$('.toggle_social_media ul li a').click(function (e) {
         var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
         var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;              
});

if ((x < 399) && (x > 400)) {
       $('#tab2').show();
}
else {
         $('#tab1').show();
}
```

I used mouse pointer click event  to find the axis of the `<p>` tags but unfortunately its not working. Can anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: make it two anchor tags that's more simple.

Comment: Why not just bind the click event on the `<p>` ?

Comment: There is also most 45+ anchor tags and popups , not possible  we can add a each anchor tag, each anchor tag has each class and each popups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `target` which is clicked and specify the tabs with a data-attribute:

**jQuery**

```
$('.toggle_social_media ul li a').click(function (e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var rel = $(e.target).data('rel');
    $('#' + rel).show();
});
```

Or if you can't change the html-markup you can use

```
 var text = $(e.target).text();
 var rel = text.toLowerCase();
```

for referencing the tab instead.

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle_social_media">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#inline_content1" class="inline1">
             <p data-rel="tab1">Tab1</p> 
             <p data-rel="tab2"> Tab2</p>
         </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/35rpe4wd/4/)**

**Reference**

[.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. Its working well..This is first time I learned 'Target' .You are awesome..

Answer (score 0):

Try this [mouseover](http://mouseover()) or [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
 $('.toggle_social_media ul li a').hover(function (e) {
         var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
         var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;              
    });
```

Comment: I think my if else condition is wrong, Can you please check and also it on mouse click event not hover...Thanks